# Fastest way to set properties to null in C# 4

Tags: c#, ienumerable

What is the fastest way to set properties (any one) to `null` in an `IEnumerable`? Is `foreach` my only option?

Comment: All properties of all objects in an `IEnumerable<YourObjectType>` or one property of all objects in an `IEnumerable<YourObjectType>`?

Comment: `foreach` is the most natural option. Why on earth would you consider such a natural and simple solution and then go looking for something else?

Comment: define 'fastest'. the code that will run the fastest, or the fastest way for you as a programmer to do it?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran the first, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving your goal:

1. As you mentioned:

   ```
   foreach(var item in enumeration)
   {
       item.Property = null;
   }
   ```
2. You can go with LINQ also:

   ```
   enumeration.ToList().ForEach(item => item.Property = null);
   ```

While the second way looks a shorter and better readable, it may execute slower, because as Jeppe Stig Nielsen pointed out, the `IEnumerable` gets converted into a `List` (be enumerating it the first time) and that list gets enumerated again, to finally set the property.

Thus you are right: `foreach` is your only option. However the `foreach`-representation will look like, you always will need to iterate over the collection to modify each item.

Comment: Your option 2 is uglier and slower. It first creates a new `List<>` object and iterates through `enumeration` (the LINQ extension). Then it iteratates through the new `List<>` object (the `ForEach` instance method on `List<>`). So two iterations instead of one, a lot of values (references) are copied in the first iteration, so more memory is used. The `List<>` instance is not kept and will be garbage collected.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks for pointing that out. I adopted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a very large list, you could consider doing this in parallel:

```
enumerable.AsParallel().ForAll(a => a.Value = null);
```

But worth benchmarking and baring in mind that your objects will now need to be threadsafe.

Quick tests **here** showed a return on investment when the list size was above 10 million items*. Lower list sizes and the costs of setting up the parallel processing outweighs the benefits.

*Your Mileage **Will** Vary

Comment: Of course the empirical 10 million limit may depend very much on the hardware architecture used (and on what else is going on on that machine).